# Integrally closed domain equivalence

Tags: commutative-algebra

I'm trying to solve the next problem:

> Let $R$ be an integral domain, and $\lbrace S_i\rbrace_i$ a family of multiplicative closed subsets of $R$ such that $R=\bigcap_i S_i^{-1}R$. Then $R$ is integrally closed if and only if each $S_i^{-1}R$ is.

From left to right I'm trying to use the fact that if the field of fractions of $R$ is $K$, the field of fractions of each $S_i^{-1}R$ is isomorphic to $K$, so i want to take an element $r/s\in K$  such that 
$$(\frac{r}{s})^n+(\frac{r}{s})^{n-1}\frac{a_1}{b_1}+\cdots+\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{0}{1}$$
where $\frac{a_j}{b_j}\in S_i^{-1}R$, and conclude that necesarlly $\frac{r}{s}\in S_i^{-1}R$, but i dont know how to proceed.
Thanks if some one can help me.

Comment: Hint. If $x\in K$ is integral over $S^{-1}R$ then there is $s\in S$ such that $sx$ is integral over $R$.

Comment: In your notation those $b_j\in S_i$ for all $j$. Clear the denominators.

Comment: Thanks your hint was perfect.